# Qt Задержка после каждой итерации в цикле

Tags: c++, qt

Как сделать задержку в цикле после каждой итерации?

```
void Programma::on_pushButton_clicked()
{
  while (true) {
   //задержка
   // исполняемый код
  }
}
```

Comment: Важно уточнить где и когда именно нужно делать задержку. Т.к. если делать sleep в гуяшном потоке, то у вас окно будет виснуть

Comment: добавил пример кода

Comment: задержка большая? или чтобы просто интерфейс не замораживался? так пока я думаю что вам нужен QApplication::processEvents() или QEventLoop + QTimer::singleSlot

Comment: думаю, это не имеет значение, если там while(true)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Подобный бесконечный цикл заблокирует главный поток. А это обычно заканчивается установкой костылей. Правильно - использовать [QTimer](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtimer.html). Вот [пример](http://qt-doc.ru/klass-qtimer.html).

Если кратко, вместо кода вида

```
void Programma::on_pushButton_clicked()
{
  while (true) {
   //задержка
   // исполняемый код
  }
}
```

пишете где то так

```
void Programma::on_pushButton_clicked()

{
  // 200 - это задержка
  QTimer::singleShot(200, this, SLOT(ex_code()));
}

void Programma::ex_code()
{
  // исполняемый код
  QTimer::singleShot(200, this, SLOT(ex_code()));
}
```

200 - это задерка в мс (1000 мс - это одна секунда).

Можно конечно сделать и явно через QTimer, Но мне такой способ показался проще.

Comment: а интервал какой? Попробуйте вместо исполняемого кода поставить просто вывод в лог.

Comment: Ваш метод сработал.

Answer (score 1):

Например, вставив (раз у вас C++) инструкцию подождать, скажем, `n` миллисекунд:

```
this_thread::sleep_for(chrono::milliseconds(n));
```

Или соответствующей функцией API операционной системы...

Я правильно понял ваш вопрос? Вы эту задержку имели в виду?

Answer (score 1):

[void QThread::sleep(unsigned long secs)](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qthread.html#sleep)

```
QThread::sleep(1); // seconds
```

Возможно, стоит рассмотреть [интервальные таймеры](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtimer.html#details), чтобы не "замораживать" интерфейс на время ожидания.

Comment: Извините, но я же не даром уточнил что в цикле после каждой итерации.

Comment: @AngelPensive, вы говорите о моем предложении в конце или мне стоило уточнить, что `sleep` нужно поместить в конце тела цикла?